# Displaying optgroup values from DB

Tags: javascript, jquery, sqlite, jquery-mobile

Basically, I have a multiselect optgroup in the jQuery Mobile style.  When the options are selected they appear as comma separated in the actual select display.  I've used this code to separate each item selected and put them each on a different row in my SQLite Table:

```
db.transaction(function(transaction) {
               var optgroup = String($('#myselect').val());
               var optarray = optgroup.split(',');
               for(var i=0; i<optarray.length; i++){
               transaction.executeSql('INSERT INTO mytable(myvalue)\
                                      VALUES(?)',[optarray[i]],
                                      nullHandler);
               }
               });
}
```

My question is:  How do I redisplay these values as comma separated when I go back onto the page with the optgroup?  To be clearer:

say I selected item1 and item2 from the select...it would look like this item1,item2

these are then broken up into two rows

row1 item1

row2 item2

Now when I go back onto that page I want to see these values that the user selected back in the optgroup in the original comma separated form.  I hope this makes sense, any help would be appreciated

EDIT:  Usually I would just select from the database and display the value on pageload with the id of the select but I need to display multiple values from multiple rows in one selectmenu

EDIT:  As suggested I tried

```
db.transaction(function(transaction) {

  transaction.executeSql('SELECT GROUP_CONCAT (columname) FROM mytable', [],
            function(transaction, result) {
            if (result != null && result.rows != null) {
            for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
            var row = result.rows.item(i);
            $('#myselect').val(row['GROUP_CONCAT(columname)']);
            }
            $('#myselect').selectmenu('refresh');
            }
            },errorHandler);
  },errorHandler,nullHandler);
```

But upon checking the value returned, it is null.  I put the group_concat line into the database checker and it correctly returns the rows comma separated but they still won't display in my select.  Not sure if the return type is the issue?  group_concat appears to return a String.

If I try displaying without group_concat then it correctly displays, but only the last element in the column

Comment: So, to clarify, you would like the values of `$('#myselect')` to be stored so that if a user comes back to the page, it shows the last selected values?

Comment: I have stored the values, it is just a case of displaying them when the user goes back on the page.  I can do this very easily if it is a normal select menu, but I'm just having trouble displaying multiple values (from multiselect) separated by commas on the actual select

Answer (score 1):

The [group_concat function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#groupconcat) returns a comma-separated list of values:

```
SELECT group_concat(myvalue) FROM mytable
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I tried it and I've edited my question with the result

Answer (score 1):

For updating the select, we can set the value by selecting the options and setting the attribute "selected" to true. And because we're using jQuery mobile, we also have to refresh the view after doing it. You can put the code in the callback after you select the rows. So something like

```
db.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql("select colname from selected;", [], function(tx, result) {
        dataset = result.rows;
        for (var i = 0, item = null; i < dataset.length; i++) {
            item = dataset.item(i);
            //set option with value in colname to true
            $("option[value="+item['colname']+"]").attr("selected",true);
        }
            $("#select-choice").selectmenu("refresh") //refresh select
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mfirdaus/A97K3/2/)

Comment: I have already stored the values which the user selected in my database (sqlite/websql).  It is now just a case of displaying those values on load of the page.  The trouble I'm having is the fact that it is a multiselect and I don't know how to display several items at once in comma separated form on the select.  I'll try and implement this answer with sqlite

Comment: Also note that when I stored the values from the multiselect, I stored each item selected on a separate row by splitting the array (code is above) so this might cause added difficulties on redisplaying

Comment: Does the updating the multiselect bit of my answer help? or is it a different multiselect/ doesn't help at all?

Comment: Your answer does exactly what I need, but in the format I have got it in and with the different storage method, I can't get it to work.  The multiselect itself is the same as my one.

If I select item1,item2,item3 it splits this array into 3 rows in my table so I'm looking for a way to rejoin this into comma forms and redisplay on the selectmenu with item1,2 and 3 selected if that makes sense

Comment: If you have an array with 3 rows, you can do `array.join(",")` to get a csv. But you can also just feed it to `$.each`, ie: `$.each(array,func(){...})` and it should work.

Comment: When I split the array and store in 3 different rows, it's no longer an array when I try to retrieve it, I did try the join method, but no luck

Comment: Actually, maybe you can put, `$("option[value="+row["colName"]+"]").prop("selected",true)` in the `executeSQL` callback, after `var row=results.rows.item(i)`. and then the selectmenu refresh after the loop.

Comment: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: option[value=Example]

Comment: Not sure what's wrong with that. But this suggests it should work: http://jsfiddle.net/mfirdaus/A97K3/2/